# I want to brew this American IPA kit with some ginger -- terrible idea or give it a go?

Tags: ginger, americanipa, ipa, honey

Love the taste of ginger, came across Papazian's Dark Gingered Ale recipe and wanted to try it out but I've already got ten gallons of dark beer in the house and I just bought this American IPA kit... would it be a terrible idea to add 1 or 2 oz of grated ginger for fifteen minutes during the boil?  My inclination is to just experiment, but I'm relatively new to homebrew and don't want to do this if it's just guaranteed to taste awful.  Also, I notice a lot of recipes that use ginger also use honey.  Any advice on incorporating honey into this recipe?  Any other spices I should throw in?

The American IPA kit:

Grains for steeping:
1.5 lbs American 2 row,
8 oz CaraHell,
8 oz CaraVienne

6.6 lbs Extra Light Malt Extract

1 oz Columbus pellets,
1 oz Columbus pellets (30 minutes),
1 oz Cascade pellets (1 min)

Wyeast 1056 American Ale yeast

OG: 1.062

Thanks in advance ya'll!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to add some ginger extract to a bottle of commercially made IPA to test it out. If you like the result, you can further experiment with the amount of ginger you think is appropriate to add to the beer. If you don't like it, then you just avoided brewing 5 gallons of beer you won't want to drink.

If you decide to do this experiment, please post your results as a comment. I'd be interested to hear how this works out.

Comment: I should say, this advice is second hand. See these related questions with similar answers:

http://brewadvice.com/questions/1686/sarsaparilla-beer
http://brewadvice.com/questions/1787/a-new-beer-with-a-hint-of-soy

Comment: thanks!  been drinking ginger tea and ipa and so far it's pretty pleasant.  think i'm going to give it a go this weekend.  will post results for sure!